# TFS Query to show items changed yesterday by specific user

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem

How can I create a TFS query that will show items changed within the last day by a specific user?

I need to view what items were completed by the team yesterday.

Answer (score 13):

I have assumed that you already know how to create a new query. These are the 3 lines that you'll need to enter into the designer...

- Team Project = @Project
- And Changed Date = @Today - 1
- And Changed By = AUser

Comment: this query ignores items that was also changed today and 
ignores items that was changed by another user after the AUser (for example, tester have closed bug).

Comment: You can't do anything about the Changed date, but you can add a "Was Ever" qualifyer to the Changed By field.

TFS2008 Does not allow you to query the history of the Changed Date

Comment: How can I have something similar for files that are checked-in?

Comment: For the Changed Date criteria, you should use `>` rather than `=`. Otherwise you will only get results that match that moment in time. Changed Date is actually represented as a datetime.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question because it returns the changed items not the completed items.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a query with these conditions

- Team Project **=** @Project
- Changed Date **=** @Today
- Changed By **Was Ever** AUser

This will consider if someone else changed the work item after that user as well

[image: Example]